# Group BY multiple using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to group by multiple fileds but having issues with it. I want to group by period,productcode.

```
var ProductUsageSummary = from b in myProductUsage
                            group b by b.ProductCode into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Period = g.Key,
                                Code = g.Key,
                                Count = g.Count(),
                                TotalQty = g.Sum(n => n.Qty),
                                Price = g.Average(n => n.Price)
                            };
```

also tried

```
var ProductUsageSummary = from b in myProductUsage
                            group b by b.Period b.ProductCode into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Period = g.Key(n => n.period),
                                Code = g.Key,
                                Count = g.Count(),
                                TotalQty = g.Sum(n => n.Qty),
                                Price = g.Average(n => n.Price)
                            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an anonymouns object to to group on multiple columns (ex... `new {prop1 prop2}`) , and the grouped fields can be accessed by `Key.PropertyName`

Try this.

```
var ProductUsageSummary = from b in myProductUsage
                          group b by new { b.Period,  b.ProductCode }into g
                          select new
                          {
                              Period= g.Key.Period,
                              Code = g.Key.ProductCode ,
                              Count = g.Count(),
                              TotalQty = g.Sum(n => n.Qty),
                              Price = g.Average(n => n.Price)
                          };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax using *Anonymous Types* :

```
group b by new { b.ProductCode, b.Period } into g
```

Then in select:

`g.Key.ProductCode` and `g.Key.Period`

Full Query:

```
var ProductUsageSummary = from b in myProductUsage
                          group b by new { b.Period b.ProductCode } into g
                          select new
                          {
                              Period = g.Key.Period,
                              Code = g.Key.ProductCode,
                              Count = g.Count(),
                              TotalQty = g.Sum(n => n.Qty),
                              Price = g.Average(n => n.Price)
                          };
```